# socket connection over internet to a dynamic public ip

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

**i am making remote desktop control** .*it is working fine on lan and i need to connect one client to another without interruption of server on internet*, i am confused with how to identify two pc's connected with interface having same public ip. I want to connect TCP client with server (both have variable public ip or may be same). what should be my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machines sharing a public IP will also have a private IP. Use that instead. If you must use the public address, you have to create a port forward.

To connect to a server on a dynamically assigned public ip:

1. Use a dynamic dns service to assign a NAME (DNS host record or A record) that will *not* change when your dynamic address changes.
2. In the router on the machine that accepts remote desktop forward a TCP port to the machine's internal IP address. This is usually TCP port 3389.

You will then be able to connect to from any internet address.

Comment: client can be on lan or internet. does teamviewe require port forwarding

Comment: If both have different public ips that change dynamically, use dynamic dns. It's a free service usually. If that's what you're doing, I'll update the answer with instructions. http://www.noip.com/ is one service.